# Rabbit MQ Web Management Console Not working

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ v3.8.3. I have followed the other posts and have explicitly enabled the web management console like this:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

But when I do localhost:15672 or localhost:5672, the web console does not open up. It says "localhost refused to connect". The server start fine. (shows completed with 0 plugins on startup)

Here is the dump from "rabbitmqctl status"

```
Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
←[1mRuntime←[0m

OS PID: 4676
OS: Windows
Uptime (seconds): 1635
RabbitMQ version: 3.8.3
Node name: rabbit@localhost
Erlang configuration: Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:64]
Erlang processes: 526 used, 1048576 limit
Scheduler run queue: 1
Cluster heartbeat timeout (net_ticktime): 60

←[1mPlugins←[0m

Enabled plugin file: D:/volpay-infra/RabbitMQ/enabled_plugins
Enabled plugins:


←[1mData directory←[0m

Node data directory: d:/volpay-infra/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@localhost-mnesia

←[1mConfig files←[0m


←[1mLog file(s)←[0m

 * D:/volpay-infra/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@localhost.log
 * D:/volpay-infra/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

←[1mAlarms←[0m

(none)

←[1mMemory←[0m

Calculation strategy: rss
Memory high watermark setting: 0.4 of available memory, computed to: 6.8201 gb
allocated_unused: 0.0358 gb (28.57 %)
other_proc: 0.0321 gb (25.59 %)
code: 0.0272 gb (21.7 %)
other_system: 0.0151 gb (12.09 %)
queue_procs: 0.0042 gb (3.32 %)
binary: 0.0036 gb (2.84 %)
other_ets: 0.0029 gb (2.34 %)
atom: 0.0014 gb (1.15 %)
connection_channels: 0.0009 gb (0.73 %)
connection_other: 0.0009 gb (0.68 %)
connection_writers: 0.0006 gb (0.44 %)
metrics: 0.0002 gb (0.18 %)
mnesia: 0.0002 gb (0.15 %)
connection_readers: 0.0002 gb (0.13 %)
quorum_ets: 0.0 gb (0.04 %)
msg_index: 0.0 gb (0.03 %)
plugins: 0.0 gb (0.01 %)
mgmt_db: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
queue_slave_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
quorum_queue_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
reserved_unallocated: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)

←[1mFile Descriptors←[0m

Total: 31, limit: 65439
Sockets: 5, limit: 58893

←[1mFree Disk Space←[0m

Low free disk space watermark: 0.05 gb
Free disk space: 735.9345 gb

←[1mTotals←[0m

Connection count: 4
Queue count: 41
Virtual host count: 1

←[1mListeners←[0m

Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: 0.0.0.0, port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0

D:\vol-infra\rabbitmq_server-3.8.3\rabbitmq_forWindows\sbin>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried starting the server in detached mode, now I have the UI console running but whenever I tried to start rabbitMQ, I get ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "localhost"